# How to detect Validator type using javascript function Page_Validators

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I wan to know that 
how can I find the type of validator through jquery using the function **Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate**

**I have one text box and 2 validators on it (1st required field validator and 2nd regular expression validator)**

**I need to change color of textbox when required flied validator validates but its working on both validator as Page_Validators return all the validator in page. 
So I want to differentiate between two validators.
need solution that how can i differntiate this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<Page_Validators.length; i++){    
    switch(Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction.name){
        case "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
            // do stuff for required field validators
            break;
        case "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
            // do stuff for custom validators
            break;
        case "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
            // do stuff for regex validators
            break;
        case "CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
            // do stuff for compare validators          
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're having to support IE8, you'll have to use this code to check the function name (.name isn't supported):

```
if(Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction.toString().indexOf('RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid') != -1) {
 // Do stuff here
```